# Replacement for org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader during migration to log4j2

Tags: java, apache, logging

After migration to from log4j to log4j2 I get error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader
```

I can't find out which class in log4j2 has overtaken function of this class. I need it for getting resources ([link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/Loader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))). I have in my project also bridge between 1 and 2 but it contains in helpers package only `NullEnumeration` class. Which class I could use to keep current functionality with new version?

Comment: isn't this one: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/LoaderUtil.html -> LoaderUtil?

Comment: would be possible to use directly ClassLoader class to get resource?

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader` class is present in
`log4j-core-2.17.1.jar`. (for 2.17.1/latest version, it would be same for other lower 2.x version)

This Loader class has the getResource method you are looking for. However, getResource method definition has changed in 2.x rather deprecated after 1.2, so minor code changes will be needed while implementing after importing the jar mentioned.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.